# "De um modo maior com que perdoamos" and "me esqueci"

Tags: português-brasileiro

I am studying Portuguese on my own.

The title is another part which I couldn't understand.

This segment is from [Pai Nosso](https://youtu.be/a0l6SDPz_8Y?t=95) (a catholic song from Priest Marcelo Rossi)

It should mean something like,
I forgive people, and so please forgive me.

But it just grammatically doesn't make sense.

Any advice would be really appreciated.

In addition, by "me esqueci", it of course is
not supposed to mean that I am suffering amnesia,
isn't it? I interpret it as "I feel lost".

Correto?

Comment: I'd say that the sentence is intended to mean "De um modo maior do que o modo com que perdoamos". Probably it is some kind of elliptical construction.

Comment: Perhaps it's as Pedro says, but for me it doesn't make sense as well. The ellipsis he mentions is agrammatical as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hi. What puzzles me the most seems to be the use of the word "maior"; what are in comparison here? Any idea?

Comment: @NJS What are in comparison here is the way we forgive people with the way God forgive us. The prayer is not asking for God forgive us ***as*** we forgive others. It is asking for God forgive us in a higher/greater way (which is possible because God is higher/greater than us).

Comment: The meaning of *Eu quase me esqueci* is *I almost forgot*, as in "I almost forgot your birthday".

Comment: @NJS In the comments above I tried to understand and explain the meaning of the sentence "De um modo maior com que perdoamos". However, you should be aware that, as far as I known, this is not a comum construction neither in the spoken language nor in the written language; neither in the colloquial language nor in the formal language; neither in the archaic lnguage nor in the modern language.

Comment: @Pedro Your explanation of the use of "maior" in the lyrics sounds pretty good; I have heard of a thing like that (such as, Only the Lord can forgive our sins), and I would buy it. But about "Eu quase me esqueci", what did I forget actually? Should I read the lyrics as "I almost forgot that your love is pretecting me"? More precisely, should I take as "esquecer que [blank]"? Thanks for being in touch with me by the way.

Comment: @NJS only for the record the original text from the bible is "perdoai-nos as nossas ofensas assim como nós perdoamos a quem nos tem ofendido".

Comment: @Pedro can you make an answer with your explanations?

Comment: The face-value interpretation is "forgive our trespasses in that major way in which we forgive [those who trespass against us]". This sounds strange. We can say "limpa com um pano verde com que limpamos habitualmente a mesa" (it would perhaps make more sense to say "limpa com **o/aquele** pano verde com que [...]", but we hear ***um*** as well), but whereas it makes sense to indentify a cloth in this way, it sounds strange to speak in this way about ways of forgiving. It would also be quite boastfull for a Christian to address God like this. So I reckon >>

Comment: >> what @Pedro suggested -- "be more forgiving to us than we are to others" -- is what the writer meant.

Comment: You should quote the part of the song that is a context to your question. As it is, it's a *very* confusing question for those who don't know the song.

Comment: @NJS If I understood correctly your last two questions, I would say Yes and No, respectively (see my answer).

Comment: @JorgeB. Yes, it is done.

Answer (score 1):

1. I'd say that the sentence ***De um modo maior com que perdoamos*** is intended to mean
   ***De um modo maior do que o modo com que perdoamos***. Maybe it is some kind of elliptical construction (but I'm not sure):

   > An *elliptical construction* is the omission from a clause of one or more words that are nevertheless understood in the context of the remaining elements ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)))

   In this case, the omitted clause is "do que o modo".
2. With respect to the word "maior", what are in comparison in the said sentence are the way we forgive people and the way God forgive us. The prayer is ***not*** asking for God forgive us ***as*** we forgive others. It is asking for God forgive us in a higher/greater way (which is possible because God is higher/greater than us).
3. The meaning of *Eu quase me esqueci* is *I almost forgot*, as in "I almost forgot your birthday". The meaning of the complete segment ***Eu quase me esqueci, me esqueci / Que o seu amor vela por mim, vela por mim*** is (as I understand it) ***I almost forgot that your love is protecting me*** (provided that you translate "vela" by "protect"). There is only one "forgotten thing". There is no space for anything different from the "love's protection".

**Remark.** I tried to understand and explain the meaning of the sentence "De um modo maior com que perdoamos". However, you should be aware that, as far as I known, this is not a comum construction neither in the spoken language nor in the written language; neither in the colloquial language nor in the formal language; neither in the archaic lnguage nor in the modern language.

Answer (score -2):

the excerpt you say "*I forgive people, and so please forgive me*" is incomplete. There are two forms of this sentence in Portuguese: "*Perdoai nossas ofenças, assim como nós perdoamos a quem nos tem ofendido*" and "*Perdoai nossas dívidas, assim como nós perdoamos aos nossos devedores*". The first form could be translated this way:"**Forgive our offenses, like we forgive who offends us**" and the second: "**Forgive our debt, like we forgive our debtors us.** "In my opinion, the second form is the most correct, because in Latin it says "debit" not "offenses".

Comment: A bit off-topic. But thanks for your contribution.

Comment: OP asked for the song Pai Nosso.